# Issue with EBS burst balance AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-ebs

I've got an EBS volume (16GB) attached to a EC2 instance that has full access to an RDS instance. The thing is I've extracted the DB to the RDS instance, so I don't use the EC2 instance for storing the web application database anymore. I did this because I was having a lot of problems with the EBS credits (they were consuming very quickly). I thought that by having the DB on a separate instance (RDS) this will decrease to almost cero the EBS credit consumption because I'm not reading nor writing on the EBS but on the RDS. However, the EBS credits keep consuming (and decrease to 0) every time users access to the web application and I don't understand why. Perhaps is because I still don't fully understand how EBS credit usage works... Can anyone enlighten me with this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You are correct that accessing RDS would not consume credits from your EBS volume... it is *something* else on your instance.  Try observing the instance's disk activity using `iostat -x 1`.  If you have a swapfile and are aggressively swapping, that is a good candidate cause for this type of issue.

Comment: Thanks! @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 1):

You can review volume types including info on their burst credits [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html). You should also review [I/O Characteristics and Monitoring](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-io-characteristics.html). From that page:

> If your I/O latency is higher than you require, check
>   VolumeQueueLength to make sure your application is not trying to drive
>   more IOPS than you have provisioned. If your application requires a
>   greater number of IOPS than your volume can provide, you should
>   consider using a larger gp2 volume with a higher base performance
>   level or an io1 volume with more provisioned IOPS to achieve faster
>   latencies.

You should review that metric and the others it mentions if this is causing you performance problems. If your IOPs are constantly above your baseline and causing them to queue you will always consume credits as fast as they are given.